# Creating a DataFrame from multiple sub vectors in R

Tags: r, dataframe

We have 1000 sub vectors starting from lst$SampleData$A1 to lst$SampleData$A1000. Can we create a dataframe by using a loop to pass the vector names.

We cannot go by static approach like mentioned below

```
data <- data.frame(lst$`SampleData$A1`,lst$`SampleData$A2`,lst$`SampleData$A3`,lst$`SampleData$A4`,lst$`SampleData$A5`)
```

as the number of vectors are very high (1000) and using the above query will take a lot of space and time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by just wrapping `data.frame` assuming that 'lst' is a `list` with `vector`s of equal `length`

```
data <- data.frame(lst)
```